# Когда я использую Avocode и PSD макет сайта, то стили "position" которые выдаёт мне avocode не подходят. В чём проблема?

Tags: html, css, windows

Допустим у меня есть PSD макет который я хочу сверстать при помощи Avocode. Когда я загружаю макет в программу и нажимаю к примеру на header элемент, он мне выдает CSS-стили для данного элемента. Когда я вставляю эти стили в CSS код, то элементы находятся на неправильных местах. Может я что-то делаю не так?

Comment: Вам заказчики потом руки не отрывают за такую верстку?

Answer (score 0):

Авокод — это просто продвинутый ФШ для верстальщиков. Удобный экспорт, удобное выделение слоев, информация о слоях прямо в CSS.
Сам по себе Авокод ничего не верстает. Это просто набор вещей, которые ускоряют саму верстку.Стили не всегда верны и точны, в крайне редких случаях Avocode может ошибиться с определением кода стиля (например, спутать значение font-weight)...Поэтому прежде чем копипастить стили, проверяйте их